# Composition in a communication protocol

Tags: c#, design-patterns, composition

I am working on a communication protocol that will communicate with a device over a USB or TCP connection.

In the code I have a class called Device that represents the device. From here I would like to be able to do two things; communicate with the device (requesting and writing data), and backup and restore of settings from the device.

I was thinking about implementing composition as follows:

```
Device
-BackupManager
--Backup()
--BackupAsync()
--Restore()
--RestoreAsync()
-RequestManager
--Request()
```

The request manager actually contains about 7 more functions all doing basically the same thing with different parameters.

The problem that I am having with this is that in order for me to perform a request, I have to call Device.RequestManager.Request().

Would you recommend leaving it this way or should the Device class implement the functions of both the BackupManager and the RequestManager and forward the calls to the appropriate component?

Answer (score 1):

- The [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) recommends you to leave it this way.
- The [Code Smell "Middle Man"](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/middle-man) recommends you to not introduce delegating methods.
- I recommend you the same

  - Disadvantage: The Client has slightly less readable code. You may rethink the naming of the classes and functions.
  - Advantage #1: Maintenance is much easier this way. This includes refactoring and debugging.
  - Advantage #2: Readability inside the Hierarchy is much easier, since the only responsibility of the container class is to contain something (Single Responsibility Principle again).

Comment: @saracaen a lightweight structure can be built inside an existing C# class either by using inner classes or just by grouping pieces of code with same purpose (or responsibility) into [C# #region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx). This way you can design the class hierarchy property and implement it in a more lightweight way